# Some macOS apps are not launching in full-screen mode

Tags: macos, catalina

I am using macOS Catalina and I noticed that a few apps in my system are not launching in full-screen mode. Every time I start those apps, I have to manually make them go full-screen.

The apps that currently display this behavior are VLC and, zoom.us.

I have followed the similar discussion in: https://osxdaily.com/2018/05/15/make-apps-open-full-screen-mac-automatically/, and unchecked the box corresponding to "Close windows when quitting an app". While it is working for most of the apps but failed for few including above two.

Is there any proper way to force the apps in question to launch full-screen every time?

Answer (score 3):

VLC has its own fullscreen structure; which means you can have the playlist windowed or fullscreen as you wish, then the movie fullscreened, either by re-using the same Space, or by invoking the Mac's native fullscreen structure, as you desire.

Prefs cover all eventualities/combinations…

[image]

VLC also has no capability to follow the Mac's "Close windows when quitting an app" pref. It always opens just the playlist window & never saves/reloads previous files automatically.

[Almost] all prefs changes in VLC require you to relaunch the app to take effect.

Zoom, I've never used.